# Seting parameter in other thread

Tags: python, multithreading

So i have a thread:

```
import threading, time, serial, logging

class SerialThread(threading.Thread):

    # SerialThread class construcor
    def __init__(self, sleep):
        self.sleep = sleep
        threading.Thread.__init__(self,name = "SerialThread")
        self.setDaemon(1)

    # SerialThread method
    def run(self):

        # Do forever
        while 1:   

            # Sleep afther every loop
            time.sleep(self.sleep)
            print 'Doing some work!'

    def setSleep(self, sleep):
         self.sleep = sleep
```

And then in my main thread i do:

```
serialThread = SerialThread(60)
serialThread.start()

def changeSleep():
    serialThread.setSleep(80)
```

Im am starting this thread from my main code. But now when i want to change the `self.sleep` number what should i do? I have tried this simple and naive solution to just create a method in the thread class, and when its called it sets the sleep time. Apparently this didnt work as i expected.
A good example would be welcome.

EDIT: added the code i tried before

EDIT: So it wont work as the `self.sleep` is always 60 as i set it in the beginning, even afther i call the `serialThread.setSleep(80)`

EDIT: Didnt think this is relevant but im creating web service with flask and `serialThread.setSleep(80)` is called by accessing the flask route. So i guess flask runs also on separate thread and because of that `serialThread.setSleep(80)` is not actually called from the main thread...

Code:

```
@app.route('/api/setConf', methods=['POST'])
def setConf():

    serialThread.setSleep(config.interval)

    return 'ok'
```

Comment: Can you give the code that you used to try your method. The method described by you should work.

Comment: @Xero: added the code i tried before

Comment: In what way does it "not work"?

Comment: @RussellBorogove: edited post with the "not work"

Comment: How are you confirming that self.sleep is 60 and not 80? Try adding a `print "sleeping for %s"%(self.sleep)` just before the `time.sleep`.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: thats exactly how im doing it

Comment: This is weird, the same code works for me. I do hope you are actually calling the changeSleep() function and not just defining it.

Comment: Works for me (with sleeps reduced to 3 and 6 seconds for testing convenience). Are you creating multiple child threads and losing track of one?

Comment: Just creating one thread

Comment: I don't know anything about flask, but my next step would be confirming that `config.interval` has the value you think it does in `setConf()`.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: yes, there is value in `config.interval`

Comment: Well, it works in a simpler case, so some assumption we're making about the system doesn't hold in the flask case. Run it down. Put a print before the infinite loop in `SerialThread.run()` to verify that there's only one child thread. Put a print in `SerialThread.setSleep` to verify that the value is getting there correctly. Tell us the other six things you didn't think were relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me with the following main body code (and a helpful print in the thread code):

```
serialThread = SerialThread(3)
serialThread.start()

def changeSleep():
    serialThread.setSleep(6)

time.sleep(15)
changeSleep()
time.sleep(15)
```

Output:

```
sleeping for 3
Doing some work!
sleeping for 3
Doing some work!
sleeping for 3
Doing some work!
sleeping for 3
Doing some work!
sleeping for 3
Doing some work!
sleeping for 6
Doing some work!
sleeping for 6
Doing some work!
sleeping for 6
```